# I defeated Skeletron and have 4 qualified houses and still have not obtained clotheir

Tags: terraria-mobile

Not a Terraria genius, so sorry if these NPCS can't be obtained this way.
Mostly explained from title, I have four qualified  houses, and I defeated  Skeletron, and still have not received clothier or dryad. Again, sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: Are the four valid houses *unoccupied*?

Comment: If I helped you, it would be nice to upvote or press the tick beside my answer :D @Kitkat3547

Comment: New NPCs won't move in until the morning - if it's still the night that you defeated Skeletron they won't move in yet

Comment: @JonK I have waited till morning and they have not moved in. I have now been waiting a day and still no NPC has moved in.

Comment: @Chippies yes. I have just built them.

Comment: Are your houses meeting the housing criteria? Have you made sure the housing is valid?

Comment: Yess. @user1337

Comment: The houses qualify as houses, I have four of em, and have defeated Skeletron, and have not received dryad or clothier.

Comment: Dryad just arrived.

Comment: NPCs don't *immediately* come to town, you should learn to be a little more patient.

Comment: One thing strikes me odd. The question asks "why hasn't X happened" and lists met criteria while the answers explains the criteria that are already met. Based on the comments, the proper answer would pretty much be "NPCs don't show up immediatly".

Comment: @Anton I have been playing for a few days now, almost playing the whole day.

Comment: Are the houses not 50 tiles or more close to corrution, have a table, chair, light, and player placed wall? If so, I have no idea. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/), these are the NPCs that will occupy your house a certian event.

### [Clothier](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Clothier)    [image: The Clothier]

He is the [Old Man](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Old_Man) guarding the [Dungeon](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dungeon). The one that summmons [Skeletron](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Skeletron) when activated. If you have a vacant house, the Clothier will move in.

### [Dryad](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Clothier)[image: The Dryad]

If any bosses are defeated in that world, the Dryad will occupy your house if it is vacant.

Comment: why is my answer downvoted?

Comment: No idea @ExplosionsPlus

Comment: @ExplosionsPlus Probably because you blatantly quoted the wiki as opposed to telling the guy why it doesnt work in **his** case regarding **his** circumstances.